# WinForm window does not display well in a high resoltution window in Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, windows-10, dpi

I'm having problems with displaying a **WinForm** Window on high-resolution monitors in Windows 10.

- I'm coming from a WPF background and I know that because of the
  **Device Independent Pixels** in **WPF**, this problem is not present there!

[image]

- The window is displayed well in Windows 10 with resolution set to
  1920x1080 though.

**Update:** 
 - The odd thing is it is displaying also well in the designer mode of
   Visual Studio in Windows 10 with 4k resolution!
 - Would hosting it inside a WPF window solve the problem?

Any suggestions on how to mitigate this problem? I'd rather move it to WPF but for now it is out of the question!

Comment: A number of machines auto change text size to say 250% when changing to 4k, and my  machine even warns me if I change from 1080 to 4k that lots of things may not react well until I reboot. so there are ramifications that arent necessarily apparently

Comment: replace **:Form** with **: Salar.DpiAware.HDpiForm** https://www.nuget.org/packages/Salar.DpiAware/ this lib claims to handle all the DPI stuff in background